# Dependency Issues In AutoMapper Type Convertors

Tags: castle-windsor, automapper

I've encountered a problem using AutoMapper and Windsor. I've created a custom type convertor that depends on another object, which can be resolved from the container but when I attempt to use the  convertor in a mapping process, an AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException is thrown, stating that my Type Convertor does not have a default constructor.

I've recreated the issue in the proof of concept code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class ObjectOne
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectTwo
{
    public string ObjName { get; set; }
    public string ObjDescr { get; set; }
}

public interface ILoggingService
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILoggingService
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class MyObjectConvertor : ITypeConverter<ObjectOne, ObjectTwo>
{
    private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

    public MyObjectConvertor(ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        if (loggingService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingService");
        _loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    public ObjectTwo Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        _loggingService.Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString());
        var source = (ObjectOne)context.SourceValue;
        return new ObjectTwo { ObjName = source.Name, ObjDescr = source.Description };
    }

    public void LogIt(string message)
    {
        _loggingService.Log(message);
    }
}

public class MappingContractsWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ILoggingService>().ImplementedBy<ConsoleLogger>(),
            Component.For<MyObjectConvertor>());
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MappingTester
{
    private IWindsorContainer container;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupFixture()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new MappingContractsWindsorInstaller());
        Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectOne, ObjectTwo>().ConvertUsing<MyObjectConvertor>();
        Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve);
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyObjectConvertorReturnedWithLoggerInjectedOk()
    {   // Proof that the Convertor is returned from the 
        // container with the dependency fulfilled
        var conv = container.Resolve<MyObjectConvertor>();
        conv.LogIt("Hello World");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ObjectOneMapsToTwo()
    {
        var source = new ObjectOne()
                    {
                        Name = "Foo",
                        Description = "Bar"
                    };

        var result = Mapper.Map<ObjectOne, ObjectTwo>(source);
        Assert.That(result.ObjName == source.Name);
        Assert.That(result.ObjDescr == source.Description);
    }
}
```

When the tests are ran, the following exception is thrown during ObjectOneMapsToTwo():

```
    Test 'MappingTester.ObjectOneMapsToTwo' failed: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Trying to map ObjectOne to ObjectTwo.
Using mapping configuration for ObjectOne to ObjectTwo
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
  ----> System.ArgumentException : Type 'MyObjectConvertor' does not have a default constructor
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
    at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
    Class1.cs(99,0): at MappingTester.ObjectOneMapsToTwo()
    --ArgumentException
    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
    at AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateCtor>b__0(Type t)
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    at AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateCtor(Type type)
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.ObjectCreator.CreateObject(Type type)
    at AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.<ConvertUsing>b__1a[TTypeConverter]()
    at AutoMapper.DeferredInstantiatedConverter`2.Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ConvertUsing>b__14(ResolutionContext context)
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.CustomMapperStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
    at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
    at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
```

This project is referencing the following:

```xml
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.5.10.11092" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="2.5.3" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.0.0" />
</packages>
```

The test MyObjectConvertorReturnedWithLoggerInjectedOk() passes, proving that the typeconvertor is being returned from the container with the dependency passed in OK. But when Automapper tries to use the convertor, it throws the exception.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in AutoMapper, fixed after the 2.0 release and will be out in the upcoming 2.1 release. You can pull down the nightlies to get the latest stable drop from [AutoMapper.org](http://automapper.org)

Comment: In a way I'm glad as I thought I was going mad. Thanks for the response Jimmy

Comment: @Jimmy Bogard Is this issue fixed now? It appears to still be a problem in AutoMapper 2.1.266 from NuGet.